# gensim loading from s3 does not work

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, gensim

I have the following code (only relevant parts shown):

```
def load_model(model_file):
    return Doc2Vec.load(model_file)

# infer 
def infer_docs(input_string, model_file, inferred_docs=5):
    model = load_model(model_file)
    processed_str = simple_preprocess(input_string, min_len=2, max_len=35)    
    inferred_vector = model.infer_vector(processed_str)
    return model.docvecs.most_similar([inferred_vector], topn=inferred_docs)
```

The code runs as a lambda on aws. It works fine when my model is small (I think that is the reason) but when I have a decent size model (~200mb) I get the following error

```
[INFO]  2018-01-21T20:44:59.613Z    f2689816-feeb-11e7-b397-b7ff2947dcec    testing keys in event dict
[INFO]  2018-01-21T20:44:59.614Z    f2689816-feeb-11e7-b397-b7ff2947dcec    loading model from s3://data-d2v/trained_models/model_law
[INFO]  2018-01-21T20:44:59.614Z    f2689816-feeb-11e7-b397-b7ff2947dcec    loading Doc2Vec object from s3://data-d2v/trained_models/model_law
[INFO]  2018-01-21T20:44:59.650Z    f2689816-feeb-11e7-b397-b7ff2947dcec    Found credentials in environment variables.
[INFO]  2018-01-21T20:44:59.707Z    f2689816-feeb-11e7-b397-b7ff2947dcec    Starting new HTTPS connection (1): s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
[INFO]  2018-01-21T20:44:59.801Z    f2689816-feeb-11e7-b397-b7ff2947dcec    Starting new HTTPS connection (2): s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
[INFO]  2018-01-21T20:45:35.830Z    f2689816-feeb-11e7-b397-b7ff2947dcec    loading wv recursively from s3://data-d2v/trained_models/model_law.wv.* with mmap=None
[INFO]  2018-01-21T20:45:35.830Z    f2689816-feeb-11e7-b397-b7ff2947dcec    loading syn0 from s3://data-d2v/trained_models/model_law.wv.syn0.npy with mmap=None
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 's3://data-d2v/trained_models/model_law.wv.syn0.npy': FileNotFoundError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/handler.py", line 20, in infer_handler
    event['input_text'], event['model_file'], inferred_docs=10)
  File "/var/task/infer_doc.py", line 26, in infer_docs
    model = load_model(model_file)
  File "/var/task/infer_doc.py", line 21, in load_model
    return Doc2Vec.load(model_file)
  File "/var/task/gensim/models/word2vec.py", line 1569, in load
    model = super(Word2Vec, cls).load(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/task/gensim/utils.py", line 282, in load
    obj._load_specials(fname, mmap, compress, subname)
  File "/var/task/gensim/models/word2vec.py", line 1593, in _load_specials
    super(Word2Vec, self)._load_specials(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/task/gensim/utils.py", line 301, in _load_specials
    getattr(self, attrib)._load_specials(cfname, mmap, compress, subname)
  File "/var/task/gensim/utils.py", line 312, in _load_specials
    val = np.load(subname(fname, attrib), mmap_mode=mmap)
  File "/var/task/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 372, in load
    fid = open(file, "rb")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 's3://data-d2v/trained_models/model_law.wv.syn0.npy'
```

First of all the file `s3://data-d2v/trained_models/model_law.wv.syn0.npy` exists and secondly to me it seems that the main model file `s3://data-d2v/trained_models/model_law` is loaded.

To validate access and existence of the file I added:

```
import smart_open
with smart_open.smart_open('s3://data-d2v/trained_models/model_law.wv.syn0.npy') as prut:
    for line in prut:
        print(line)
```

which works just fine printing.

Can you help?

Comment: I have now run through the code using pdb. I can confirm that model_law is loaded from the s3 bucket

Comment: I have now added a work around where the lambda function downloads the model files using boto and read the model from the /tmp folder on the lambda function instance. Works but is slow

Answer (score 4):

Loading models using s3 buckets is at the moment not possible when the models are split in multiple files. I have posted a feature request on github

https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/issues/1851

Comment: Hi Jens, 
Not sure if there have been recent developments in the libraries, can't really find it. Have you been able to solve multi-file loading from S3?